# I can't see my Layout (Monodroid + MS Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin.android

I'm making a very simple software with a TCP Listener that (until now) only receives a message from a TCP Client codified in ASCII and I'll have to do something with the UI that I still don't know, but by now, I'm just trying to show an AlertDialog with this message on Samsung Galaxy Tab.

The problem is that, I believe that for some reason the setContentView is not working. I have one .axml (layout) file with an AbsoluteLayout, and I'm calling this AbsoluteLayout on code, changing its color, and trying to show this AbsoluteLayout (with its color changed) on the screen, but the problem is that I just see the regular black screen.

I started debugging the code, and I can see the all the Console.Writeline commands on the output of the MS VS 2010, even the message sent from the client. But I can't see the layout and the AlertDialog.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Gafisa.Automacao.VideoWall.Listener
{
    [Activity(Label = "Listener", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        AbsoluteLayout abs = FindViewById<AbsoluteLayout>(Resource.Id.abslayout);
        abs.SetBackgroundColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(125,125,125,125));
        //ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
        //var lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50, 200, 200);
        //btn.LayoutParameters = lp;
        //BitmapDrawable dd = new BitmapDrawable("/mnt/sdcard/1.png");
        //btn.SetBackgroundDrawable(dd);
        //abs.AddView(btn);

        System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener listener = null;
        byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[40];
        int bytesRcvd;

        try
        {
            listener = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13000);
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Listener iniciado");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro ao iniciar o listener: " + se.Message);
        }

        for (;;)
        {
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netStream = null;
            try
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                netStream = client.GetStream();
                int totalBytesEchoed = 0;
                while ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    netStream.Write(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);
                    totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
                }
                string recebido = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBuffer);
                Console.WriteLine(recebido);

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetMessage(recebido);
                alert.SetTitle("Mensagem Recebida");
                alert.Show();
                Console.WriteLine("echoed {0} bytes.", totalBytesEchoed);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Erro no LOOP");
            }
            finally
            {
                netStream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

By running an infinite loop in this `OnCreate` function, you prevents the UI framework from finishing rendering. That's why what you see is only the black screen.

You are supposed to run non-UI code asynchronously (in a separate thread).

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
 {
   for (;;)
        {
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netStream = null;
            try
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                netStream = client.GetStream();
                int totalBytesEchoed = 0;
                while ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    netStream.Write(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);
                    totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
                }
                string recebido = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBuffer);
                Console.WriteLine(recebido);
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                   AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                   alert.SetMessage(recebido);
                   alert.SetTitle("Mensagem Recebida");
                   alert.Show();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("echoed {0} bytes.", totalBytesEchoed);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Erro no LOOP");
            }
            finally
            {
                netStream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also with Mono for Android (Xamarin.Android) you should use `Log.Info(string tag, string message)` where tag is the name of calling class. Don't use `Console.WriteLine(string)`. You can also use `Log.Warn(string, string)` and `Log.Error(string, string)`